# Delay in debt appearing on credit card statement

Tags: credit-card

We charged hospital fees totalling $2400 on a St George Bank credit card on 17 and 21 April 2014. The hospital was located in Denpasar Bali.   On last checking the amount owed on the card (12/05/2014) in Sydney, we were advised that no account from the hospital has appeared.  It is now three weeks since the transaction occurred and still there is no indication from St George bank that any money is owed them in relation to the hospital fees.  Does anyone have a possible explanation for what might have occurred.

Comment: Is there any hold showing up .. typically the available limit on card should go down and most cards also Outstanding Authorization Amount ... ie charged but not yet processed. Some Merchant Banks / Card Types require physical swipe for the transaction to be honoured and then paper signed slips to be provided so the charge to be valid. If the Hospital has not done this or is taking time.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a delay in the hospital's administration processing the payment or they may have misplaced or lost the payment paperwork details. You will just need to keep checking your statement in case the payment still comes through at a later date.

Comment: May also be worth calling the hospital and checking.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton - the hospital is in a foreign country where the language barrier and differing policies might make it a difficult to get a straight answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the hospital is run like hospitals in the US it can take a long time just to determine the bill. The hospital, Emergency room, ER doctors, surgeons, anesthesiologists, X-Ray department, pharmacy and laboratory are considered separate billing centers. It  can take a while to determine the charges for each section.

Is there an insurance company involved? When there is one involved it can take weeks or months before the hospital determines what the individual owes. The co-pays, coverages, and limits can be very confusing.

In my experience it can take a few months before the final amount is known.

You may want to call the hospital to determine the status of the bills.

Comment: Note that in this case, the fees have already been charged to the credit card.

Comment: They have scanned my card when checking out from the hospital, but still took months to determine what the final charges will be.

Comment: I got my last bill for my daughter's birth in Jan 2014. She was born Jun 2013

Comment: Yeah, but the OP knows the exact amount of the charge. It was $2400, charged over two dates.